# Can I call object methods without inheriting their classes

Tags: java, collections

I implement an Array list in Zoo.java which doesn't inherit any other classes.I will add some objects to this

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
al.add(new Cat());
al.add(new Dog());
```

I am unable to write logic which will tell me which type of object is called and using the methods of that class without using Inheritance and Generics.

so here can  i use:

```
                   for(Animal a:al)
                   class <?> X = obj.getClass(a);
                   ((X)a).somemethod();
```

Comment: Can you perhaps show *how* you're trying to make those method calls?

Comment: you mean when you call `al.get` - you don't know which type of Object you will get?

Comment: You could use instanceof to check what type of object you try to access and act accordingly.

Comment: you can check which class is the object by doing obj.getClass()/instanceof and then conversion ((Dog)al).someDogsAction()).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Which methods do you want to call? `Cat`'s, `Dog`'s, `Object`'s? What do these methods look like?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Who exactly upvotes such input? ... beyond that: don't use names that are already used by libraries. Calling your own class `ArrayList` just confuses your reader. Dont do that!

Comment: And of course, the deeper question is "why". Why would you want to invent your own deficient wheel, when there is already a List/ArrayList that works nicely with generics in standard Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some work on it. To access the methods of objects that are in the array list we can use java.lang.reflect package.

I can first get all the declared methods and then invoke them by using parameters.

so my program will be like:

```
                  public class Methodcall{
                       ArrayList <Object> al =  new ArrayList<Object>();
                        al.add(new Cat());
                        al.add(new Dog());
                        for(Object a:al)
                           {
                               class ax = a.getClass();
                               Method[] methods=ax.getdeclaredMethods();
                               for(Method m:methods)
                                 {
                                    System.out.println(method.getName);
                                  }
                            }
                 }
                }
```

after this we can access methods by using other members of reflections.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the array list of super class type.

You can do this.

```
ArrayList<Zoo> arrayList=new ArrayList<Zoo>();
```

Comment: `Zoo` is a collection class, "which doesn't inherit any other classes"

Answer (score 1):

The lesson to learn here is *polymorphism".

the classes `Cat` and `Dog` should implement a commont *interface* that declares methods available for them:

```
interface Animal {
   void eat(SomeOtherInterface food);
   void giveSound(BufferedWriter output);
   void move();
}

class Cat implements Animal {
   @Override public void eat(SomeOtherInterface food){
        // consume the food
   }
   @Override public void giveSound(BufferedWriter output){
        output.write("Meaw");
   }
   @Override public void move(){
      // move within the world
   }
}

class Dog implements Animal {
   @Override public void eat(SomeOtherInterface food){
        // consume the food
   }
   @Override public void giveSound(BufferedWriter output){
        output.write("Woof");
   }
   @Override public void move(){
      // move within the world
   }
}
```

Then you give your collecton a *generics* parameter of the most generic common type providing the methods you want to access:

```
Collection<Animal> myAnimals = new ArrayList();
myAnimals.add(new Cat());
myAnimals.add(new Dog());

try( BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))){
   for(Animal animal : animals)
      animal.giveSound(output); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any `instanceOf` checks there is no other way to do it; unless your `ArrayList::add` has a definition that says to take some general Object and that `Cat` and `Dog` extends from. But still the only methods you would be able to call would be the methods from that `Object`, even if `Cat` or `Dog` have additional ones. You might see why generics are so handy in these cases...

Comment: what about object.getClass()?

Comment: @vmrvictor still a `check` against the `class`; but think about it - you expose such an `ArrayList`, so getting the class or checking against `instanceOf` for what types? All of them? Or just assume that *only some* will be put?

Comment: well that depends on the problem to be solved, the question asks if there is a way of do this with no inheritance/generics, instanceof checks inheritance

Comment: How to use instanceof method in this case.

Comment: @PradheerKk it all depends on what `get` in your implementation returns...